# API call succeeds locally but fails after website is published, even after using WebProxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I have a site in asp.net MVC which sends SMS to users through a 3rd party API.
The API works as planned when I test locally but fails with the following error once I upload onto the web. This is the error it throws:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 80.85.87.122:443"

Originally I was attempting to access the API using HTTP GET then switched to POST using XML, the latter approach returned the following error:
Unable to connect to the remote server at

> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

My code to consume the resource is below:

```
private async Task SendSmsUsingXML()
        {
            WebRequest req = null;
            WebResponse rsp = null;
            try
            {
                string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MultiTexterSMSFormat.xml");
                string uri = "https://www.multitexter.com/tools/xml/Sms.php";
                req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
                req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
                req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type
                //req.Proxy = new WebProxy("202.79.27.50", 8080);
                // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
                // Write the XML text into the stream
                writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
                writer.Close();
                // Send the data to the webserver
                rsp = req.GetResponse(); //I am getting error over here
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
                string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                Response.Write(result);

            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
            {
                Response.Write(webEx.Message.ToString());
                Response.Write(webEx.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
                Response.Write(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
                if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
            }
        }
```

Again, this worked locally but failed once I published unto the web.
I then contacted my host(www.1and1.com) since all fingers seemed to point at them being the problem.
Their customer care informed me that this request was being blocked as a result of the limitations of my hosting package(which is a shared hosting package) and it would no longer be an issue if I **upgraded** to a dedicated server package.
This made no sense to me as a simple API call is part and parcel of even the most basic sites.
After doing more digging I found a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67e119d0-68e9-47b8-aa19-50eac0c2e78f/httpwebrequest-getrequeststream-error?forum=wpnotifications) where a user complained of the same issue with the same hosting company. His solution was to use a proxy server, leading to 1and1 accepting the request.
I went online, looked for a free proxy servers and ports for testing purposes, I located one that worked locally, uploaded it unto the live site and it still failed with this error:

> Unable to connect to the remote server at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

I really am at my wits end at this point and would genuinely appreciate any help and/or recommendations on solving this.
For further reference, this is the [link](https://www.multitexter.com/tools/docs/HTTP_SMS_API.pdf) to the documentation of the SMS API I am attempting to consume.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to create a virtual machine in the cloud and host it there. I had the same issue with GoDaddy so I moved to Azure virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks @RICKYKUMAR. We've moved the site unto a windows server with a public IP.

Comment: I have posted the same and answer will you please mark it as answer so that it will help others to find solution thanks in advance @Ozone

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a virtual machine in the cloud and host it there. I had the same issue with GoDaddy so I moved to Azure virtual machine.