# Google API call fails from an ASP.NET Web API application hosted on shared Windows hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, shared-hosting

I have created an ASP.net Web API application. This application has an API that receives sku Id and purchase token from my Android app, verifies the purchase and returns an appropriate result. Now, the issue is, when I run my application locally, it runs fine. Google returns me a response and I can process it. But when I host this application on my shared Windows hosting server, this call fails. It simply fails, there is no error.

Here is my Web API.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Api/Files/GetFiles")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFiles(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    string skuId = fileInfo.SkuId;
    string purchaseToken = fileInfo.PurchaseToken;
    ProductPurchase productPurchase = GoogleAPIConnector.GetProductPurchaseInfo(skuId, purchaseToken);
}
```

Here is the 'GetProductPurchaseInfo' function.

```
public static ProductPurchase GetProductPurchaseInfo(string productId, string purchaseToken)
        {
            string packageName = "my.package.name";

            string sFileContents = "my p12 file contents as a byte array";

            byte[] baFileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(sFileContents);

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(baFileContents,
                            "notasecret",
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet
                        );

            var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("my publisher account on google play service")
                    {
                        Scopes = new[] { AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher }
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            var service = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = "my application name",
            });

            return service.Purchases.Products.Get(packageName, productId, purchaseToken).Execute();
        }
```

I am at my wits end trying to find a solution. Can this be because API calls are prohibited in a shared hosting environment? I think this can be the only reason because this call is successful when the application is run locally. Or am I missing some configuration on the server?

Comment: "It simply fails, there is no error." - how can it fail without an error? Are no exceptions raised? Do you have an exception handler or logging anywhere?

Comment: @Dai: The call to GetProductPurchaseInfo is placed inside a try catch block. And the exception is being logged. As an additional measure, I am writing two log messages - one before and one after the call to GetProductPurchaseInfo. I can see only the first message in the log file. This means that service.Purchases.Products.Get(packageName, productId, purchaseToken).Execute() never returns.

Comment: Well, is there any IP restriction on the google api?

Comment: @Canela: I don't know. I have asked them many times, but the (in)famous customer care team of Godaddy has not been able to provide a definite answer to me. But this seems to be a common theme. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190704/api-call-succeeds-locally-but-fails-after-website-is-published-even-after-using

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing my web hosting provider. I went with Accuwebhosting. I deployed my code, called the API using Postman and was able to get a response.

So, this was GoDaddy's fault. (One more reason to hate them?)